# "unexpected '=' "

Tags: coffeescript

I try to compile this .coffee file into .js, but it gives me error:

```
In projekt.coffee, Parse error on line 122: Unexpected '='
```

here is the specific part:

```
#line122 -># quotes = ["The people who were trying to make this world worse are not taking the day off. Why should I? <br> -Bob Marley", "Don't worry about a thing, every little thing is gonna be alright<br> -Bob Marley", "Better to die fighting for freedom then be a prisoner all the days of your life.<br> -Bob Marley", "Herb is the healing of a nation, alcohol is the destruction of mankind<br> -Bob Marley", "When you smoke the herb, it reveals you to yourself.<br> -Bob Marley", "My music fights against the system that teaches to live and die.<br> -Bob Marley"]
        quoteNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length) 
        $('#cytat').html '<p> #{quotes[quoteNumber]} <p>'.css 
            font-family : Finger Paint
```

ande here the whole code:

http://jsfiddle.net/BNMa7/

i dont really know whats going on since it tells me that '=' is unexpected, but it clearly defines an array. help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple problems with this that we should address before the syntax error you're describing.

`font-family` is not a valid stand-alone key. You need to quote that in order to compile it correctly. Same with `Finger Paint` -- I don't know what's up with that.

String interpolation doesn't work with single quoted strings. You need to use double quotes if you want `#{quotes[quoteNumber]}` to be replaced with the quote at that index.

With these fixed, we still have a big problem with operator precedence:

```
$('#cytat').html "<p> #{quotes[quoteNumber]} <p>".css 
    'font-family': 'Finger Paint'
```

That's equivalent to:

```
$('#cytat').html("<p> #{quotes[quoteNumber]} <p>".css('font-family': 'Finger Paint'));
```

Which is *probably* not what you meant, since strings don't have a `.css()` method. Add parens around the `.html()` call to get it to the correct meaning:

```
$('#cytat').html("<p> #{quotes[quoteNumber]} <p>").css
    'font-family': 'Finger Paint'
```

Now, finally, the syntax error. At first glance, this appears to be perfectly valid code, and the error message isnt' very helpful... but this code has a fatal mistake. Do you see it? There's nothing wrong with the sample you posted; this is only wrong in the context of the rest of the file. So what is it?

You've mixed tabs and spaces. *Never* mix tabs and spaces. The CoffeeScript compiler is apparently using a different tab width than your editor, so it freaks out, and gives you a crazy error message.

Consider using a text editor that will automatically translate tabs into (a consistent number of) spaces, or at the very least one that allows you to view invisible characters. I like Sublime Text, but there are plenty of options out there.